# psuedo code to find repeating number?

Tags: arrays

Array has total 101 values. This array contains numbers from 1 to 100 and one number is repeating (two times). Write psuedo code to find repeating number.

Comment: What is this? Homework? Challenge? Spam?

Comment: Agree, it almost seems like a cut and paste out of the assignment!

Answer (score 0):

1. You could hash the values and detect
   collisions
2. You could sort the array then loop
   it finding duplicates
3. You could search the array (long and
   slow!)

If you want to be smart, take a look at hashing.  If you want to play it easy and safe, sorting the list with merge sort then looping the indexes would probably be best.

Comment: Sorting the array would be O(N log N), and that's if you pick a decent sort algorithm.  A linear search, with an array of "seen" flags, would be faster (O(N), and the operations trivial).  That last part is key, though -- comparing each entry with every other is indeed "long and slow", so don't do it unless there's an O(1) way of answering the question "have i seen this number before?".

Comment: How do you have a 'seen' flag though?  That's the problem!

Comment: Would be trivial in languages that provide sets or dictionaries. Traverse the array, and add a number to a set if it is not already there. If it is, you have your duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add up all the indexes [0] -> [100] find out what 1 + 2 + 3 ... + 100 should equal subtract that from your result and you got the repeating number.

So you'd just have a simple

`for` or `while` loop going through each index then subtract the 2 and you have your result.

Something like...

```
q = 0;
p = 101 * 50;
for(i<=100; i <array.length; i++){
 q += q + array[i]
 }
 repeating number = q-p;
```

Comment: Clever :) (and some obligatory noise to reach "enough" chars)

Comment: You don't even have to add all the numbers 1 to 100 to find out the total. It's simply 101 * 50 = 5050.

Comment: For reference, the easy way to calculate 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + 100 would be `(1 + 100) * 100/2`.  Works for any two numbers; just replace `1` with the low number and `100` with the high one.

Comment: @Guffa @cHao Thanks guys, not thinking striaght :)

Comment: yes but what if you want to know the index of this repeating number?

Comment: @Darknight I simply answered the question, no more, no less. If you were to do that "divide and conquer"

Comment: Or have an array of "this number's been seen" flags.  Loop through the array, check the flag for that number.  If it hasn't been set, set it and keep going; otherwise, you've found the number.  This won't scale well to huge arrays (as it'll require at least some percentage of the array size for the flags), but for a few hundred (or even a few thousand), it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (C#):

```
int[] array = ... ; // initialize appropriately
var hashSet = new HashSet<int>();
var indexOfDuplicate = -1;
for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) {
   if (hashSet.Contains(array[i])) {
      indexOfDuplicate = i;
      break;
   }
   hashSet.Add(array[i]);
}
var duplicateNumber = array[indexOfDuplicate];
```

With this solution you will have both the index of the duplicate number (2nd occurrence) and the duplicate number.

Answer (score 0):

Set set;

for each p in array {
  set.add(p);
}

print(set);